# How to - Every successive dynamically-created drop down to not have the selected values of the previous drop downs

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have button that dynamically creates a drop down on every click. I want every successive drop down (which has also dynamic option tags) to not have the selected values of the previous drop down as options

This is how the dynamic drop down gets created

```
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT id ,concat(Opponenttype,' - ', OpponentName , ' - RefNo - ',Refnumber,' ',OpponentStatus) as Opponent FROM wp_opponents where status=1 order by refnumber";
    if($results  = $wpdb->get_results( $sql)){
        $OpponentOptions ="";
         foreach($results as $row){  
       
        $OpponentOptions = $OpponentOptions."<option value=$row->id>$row->Opponent</option>";
     }

    }
    ?>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   
     var options=  '<?php echo $OpponentOptions; ?>';
     var c=<?php echo $GLOBALS['counter'];?>;
        $('#AddOpponent').click(function(){
              c=c+1;
            var str="<br> <br> <p>Opponent No. " + c +"</p> <select id=\"opponent_id" + c +"\"  name=\"opponent_id" + c +"\" class=\"form-control input sm select2 opponents\">" + options +"</select>   ";
           vc='#opponent_id' + c;
           $( "#AppendForm" ).append(str);
           $("#Oppcounter").val(c);
            $(vc).select2(); // adding select2 (search dropdown) to the dynamically created select tags above
           //alert(str);
    
    
      });

     **EDIT**
     var previous;

  $(".opponents").on('focus', function () {
      // Store the previous value 
       previous = this.value;
    
   }).change(function() {

    str=$(this).val();

   $(".opponents").not(this).find("option[value='"+str+"']").remove();
    });
   if (previous){
    //$(".opponents").not(this).append('<option value="+${previous}+" > '"+${previous}+"' </option>');
      $(".opponents").not(this).append( new Option(previous, previous));
             }
       previous = this.value;
     });

            });

                  });

  </script>
```

How do I prevent every successive drop down from having an option that was selected in the previous drop downs

Comment: Whenever a "change" event happens on any dropdown, get the option ID which it was changed to, and remove that option ID from the subsequent ones. For that you'll need to know how to handle "change" on a dropdown in Javascript (easy to google), how to get the selected ID (easy to google), how to determine which dropdowns are "subsequent" (tricker, but very possible if you structure your HTML sensibly and/or use some naming convention), and how to remove an option from a dropdown by its ID (again not so hard to google). Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Since the drop downs are created dynamically I cant readily take the id of the dropdown. it has to be opponent_id1, opponentid2, opponent_id3 based on number of times clicked. Will a for loop with a counter work in this scenario?

Comment: `I cant readily take the id of the dropdown`...well you could either a) write loop code which knows how to build the ID string, and keeps going until it doesn't find an element matching the generated ID, or b) give all dropdowns the same class and select all of them at once using that. Or some combination of the above, so you can work out which ones come "after" the clicked one.

Comment: Added a for loop with counter to dynamically create the change event handler function. Doesn't seem to be working as now the button doesn't respond to click. Can you check the code in the edited section of the question

Comment: Hmm. At first glance, `$("#opponent_id"+i option[value='"+str+"'])` looks like it would produce a syntax error. Instead of saying "doesn't seem to be working", try doing some basic debugging such as checking the console for errors, and using the debugger to trace code and variables, and then you can narrow down the issue a bit. Also, even if you fix that, it looks like it's going to remove the option from the same dropdown that's just been changed, not the other ones.

Comment: P.S. Rather than looping to set a separate change event on every dropdown, if you give them all the same class (e.g. `class="opponents"`) then you could lose the `for (i = 2; i <= c; i++) {` loop and just write `$(".opponents").change(function() {
     var str = $(this).val();`. This will attach a handler to all elements with that class, and `this` ensures that the value of the currently selected one is chosen. You don't need to match the specific option, you can use val() on the dropdown itself to get the currently selected value.

Comment: I have edited the code and I think it should be fine now but my website doesn't produce expected results.  I tried this code independent of my website, it is doing as expected. However I think `option[value='"+str+"']` has a problem as, without this, all other dropdowns get removed but with this it doesn't do as expected. **PS** There are no errors in the console. Can you help if this piece of selector  `option[value='"+str+"']` is correct in syntax in the code. Please check the edited section? @ADyson

Comment: `it doesn't do as expected`...does it do something else instead? Or just nothing? Be precise please. I suspect that `$(".opponents option[value='"+str+"']").not(this)` doesn't make sense because `this` is a `<select>` not an `<option>` so it's unlikely to filter it out.

Comment: `does it do something else instead? Or just nothing?` Does nothing. Ohk so its targeting `option` not `select` tag @ADyson

Comment: You need to split the selector: `$(".opponents").not(this).find("option[value='" + str + "']").remove();` Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pLx4rut5/. Now you just need to work out how to put back the previously selected value into the other dropdowns - which was presumably removed but needs restoring because now it's valid again... could be interesting.

Comment: The code works fine when tried independent of the website but doesn't work on the website. There are no errors in the console and I took some days to thoroughly find the problem couldn't succeed. By the way I am using wordpress and I know that instead of  `$`,   `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});` should be used. However `$` works fine on my wordpress website as I am using this for other stuffs perfectly. Can you help in pointing out the cause of the problem?

Comment: Beside that, for the second part of the logic, inorder to put back the previously selected value into other dropdowns, I have am storing the previous value on focus event and then adding it to the dropdowns on change event. Doesn't work (No console errors) Please check the edited section of the code